# Two images overlapping another one

Tags: html, image, css

I got a problem with transparency of one of the images. Left and center image is fine. But the right one isn't hidden behind center one. Was trying overflow: hidden and z-index but no luck. Am I doing something wrong? Or maybe it's better way to achieve something like this?

```
Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/21240/
```

Comment: Can you include your code in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to declare `positioning` in order for `z-index` to work.

Add the bellow to your current styles.

```css
#ekrany .container > div:nth-child(3) img {
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}
```